# Ligbdx - How to exit app when touch a button?

Tags: java, android, libgdx, exit

I would like to know how to exit my libgdx app when touch a button.

```
Inside class that implements Screen and InputProcessor.

public void show(){
    ........
    exitButton= new TextButton("Exit", style);
    exitbutton.setPosition(50,50);
    ........
}
public void render(){
    ........
    exitButton.draw(batch, 1f);
    ........
}
```

Now how and where put the condition to exit the app when touch this button?

Comment: TextButton is intended to be used with Stage, which acts as the InputProcessor and manages presses on the buttons (read the documentation on libgdx scene2d). To react to Button presses, add an EventListener to it and put your response code in the EventListener's method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a class that implements InputProcessor (an Interface), you must implement InputProcessor's methods. Normally a Stage class would be used (which has implementations of these methods). But if you're not using that, you'd need to do it yourself, or your code won't compile. The method you're looking for specifically is likely

```
boolean touchDown(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button)
```

Place your code to determine an app exit here. If you're not getting a compile error, then your code is structured to already catch this (like using Stage, as mentioned above), in this case you'll need to override the parent class's implementation of touchDown() to do what you need.

Comment: I have that function on my code, but i dont know how put "if i press the textbutton, then...". I tried using exitButton.isPressed(), but it didn´t work.

Comment: Without knowing how your class is setup (that implements InputProcessor), or what else you have structured, it is hard to pinpoint the issue. Are you using a stage and adding Actors (ie: your button) to it? Stage is great in that it handles the higher level input calculations, and then you can, for example, add listeners to individual actors if you want them to do something. The stage will then pass inputs to the actors. A quick search yielded this, which seems like a good intro for you: http://libgdx.toxsickproductions.com/libgdx/libgdx-basics-create-a-simple-menu/

Comment: As I said earlier (and I see Tenfour04 is saying the same thing in a comment to your original question), look into the Stage class, see how it works, and read through the link I posted for a sample. Stage/EventListeners are the intended ways to use TextButton (and Actors - TextButton is derived from Actor)